# add the division symbol on OpenOffice Writer (Word) on Mac OS X

Tags: snow-leopard, word-processor, open-office

How can I add the division symbol on OpenOffice Writer (Word) on Mac OS X?

I cannot seem to find a way to add this symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division symbol ÷ can be written in any editor (OpenOffice, Word, Safari text fields, Pages, TextEdit etc) with the key combo Option-/

Comment: Thanks, I actually had to look up the Option key, but for anyone else looking it is this one http://ipad4schools.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/option-keyboard.png